# Jquery : Create multiple div separately

Tags: jquery

My JQuery code creates multiple divs on the click of a button using a while-loop.

```
$(document).on("click",".ball_link", function makeDiv(){
count=0;
//ajax code to fetch no. of divs to be created from table

    while(count< no_of_divs)
    {

    //code to calculate random x,y coordinates and save them to posx and posy

    var newdivid='div'+count;
    $newdiv = $('<div/>').css({
    'position':'absolute',
    'left':posx+'px',
    'top':posy+'px',
    'display':'none',
    'background':'ball.png'
    }).appendTo( '.page-wrap' ).fadeIn(600).effect("bounce", { times:6, distance:15 },300);
    count++;
    }
});
```

The problem is that if the no_of_divs is for eg 3, then all 3 divs appear at the same time on the page. How can I force them to come one by one, without removing the while loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a slight change - add a delay to the animation...

```
$(document).on("click",".ball_link", function makeDiv(){
count=0;
//ajax code to fetch no. of divs to be created from table

    while(count< no_of_divs)
    {

    //code to calculate random x,y coordinates and save them to posx and posy

    var newdivid='div'+count;
    $newdiv = $('<div/>').css({
        'position':'absolute',
        'left':posx+'px',
        'top':posy+'px',
        'display':'none',
        'background':'ball.png'
    }).appendTo( '.page-wrap' ).delay(900 * count).fadeIn(600).effect("bounce", { times:6, distance:15 },300);
    count++;
    }
});
```

I set the delay to `900 * count` as 900 is the total animation time for the fade and the bounce.  Play about with that value to get it how you like it :)

Comment: this will work _most_ of the time, but does not guarantee that subsequent animations will wait until the previous ones have finished.

Comment: If that doesn't work then he'll have to go down the route of having a create function with a callback method that calls the create function again (if all the divs are not shown).  That's quite involved for a simple show animation, which is what this is.

Comment: Thanks that works nicely! I was using delay(500) earlier which was still making them appear together. The '* count' did the trick. Can you tell me why were they coming together, even though they were created in different iterations of the loop ?

Comment: @soundswaste they come together because each element has its own animation queue - queueing an animation on the second `<div>` won't wait for the first to complete.

Comment: The loop will complete almost instantly, appending each div at pretty much the same time, so you need to multiply the delay by count to account for that.

Answer (score 2):

i think you can delay by the jquery [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) below

```
appendTo( '.page-wrap' ).delay(900 * count).fadeIn(600).effect("bounce", { times:6, distance:15 },300);
```